# Rails 6: connection_pool.rb segmentation faul

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am getting a really odd segmentation fault error when trying to access a Rails 6.0.6 app.

When I run `rails s` and try to access the root path on localhost the errors in the console are too large to capture here, so I've recorded them with `rails s &> err.log`. I am seeing the following:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.6 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
[3163] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3163] * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 2.7.8-p225) ("Birdie's Version")
[3163] *  Min threads: 5
[3163] *  Max threads: 5
[3163] *  Environment: development
[3163] *   Master PID: 3163
[3163] *      Workers: 2
[3163] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
[3163] * Preloading application
[3163] * Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
[3163] * Listening on http://[::1]:3000
[3163] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[3163] - Worker 0 (PID: 3184) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
[3163] - Worker 1 (PID: 3185) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
source=rack-timeout id=128022b8-ca22-44ed-9cda-f214b42540ab timeout=123000ms state=ready
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-12 19:41:30 +0700
source=rack-timeout id=128022b8-ca22-44ed-9cda-f214b42540ab timeout=123000ms service=1ms state=active
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:337: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x000000011026cade
ruby 2.7.8p225 (2023-03-30 revision 1f4d455848) [arm64-darwin22]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :sleep
c:0002 p:0016 s:0008 e:000007 BLOCK  /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:3 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:---- s:0003 e:000002 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:337:in `block in spawn_thread'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:337:in `sleep'

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: puma: cluster worker 1: 3163 [octopi]

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 ruby2_keywords.rb
    5 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/enc/encdb.bundle
    6 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    7 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0/arm64-darwin22/rbconfig.rb
    8 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    9 /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
```

The output is very large so I can't paste it all here. However, it seems like the issue is coming from:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.8/gems/activerecord-6.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:337: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x000000011026cade
```

I suspect this has something to do with PostgreSQL but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

If I run a Rails console, I can do the following:

```rb
2.7.8 :001 > puts "Hello"
Hello
```

So that's fine. The issue seems to happen when accessing the database:

```rb
User.first # This causes a segfault
```

After a lot of Googling, I've managed to get the app working if I use the following setting in `databases.yml`:

```yaml
development:
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  pool: 5
  gssencmode: disable
```

That `gssencmode: disable` seems to do the trick. However, it's not a setting that seems reasonable to keep as I believe it disables some PostgreSQL security feature.

I am running a Homebrew managed postgresql@12 version

Other details:

- Ruby 2.7.8
- PostgreSQL 12.15 on arm-apple-darwin22.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1), 64-bit
- MacBook Pro (M1 chip)
- MacOS Ventura 13.4

I'm pretty stumped on this one. Any help to get this working without disabling `gssencmode` would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am getting the exact same behavior today. I have yet to find a solution. My machine is Intel Mac running MacOS X Monterey, PG12, Ruby 2.7.7. I can also report your `gssencmode: disable` works on my machine too.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I am on Mac OS Monterey 12.6.2v. Adding `gssencmode: disable` worked for me as well.